# Forcing eclipse to provide stubs for implementation of pure virtual functions in a derived class

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The use case in Eclipse:

C++ code as follows:

Create a new class Bar that inherits from class Foo

Class Foo has pure virtual functions.

Is there a way to force Eclipse to create stubs for the implementation of those pure virtual functions in the newly created derived class?

Comment: Someone has requested close as "unclear what you're asking", but it's perfectly clear. I know I've done that for Java code, but not C++ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep an eye on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303870 , or heck, help them implement it.